# Synchronize Sqlite databases found on WinForm app and Xamarin Form app

Tags: winforms, sqlite, xamarin.forms, synchronization

I have a Winform app connected to Sqlite database located on local machine. Also, I have Xamarin from app connected to Sqlite database on same phone (offline storage). I want to synchronize these databases.

What I do so far is uploading database from the Winfrom app to a web server then download it on Xamarin app (and vice versa). However, this is very bad method because user should do the upload/download every time there is a database change.

I there a better way to do the synchronization?

The database is located in three locations, local machine, web server and the mobile. So I suppose that there is a way to synchronize these databases by making the database on server the main database so that the other databases can be synchronized with it.

I found litesync library, but I couldn't find a simple example of how to do the synchronization.

**Update:**
The problem with litesync is that there is no simple way of installing this library to my project (Winform or Xamarin).
I have tried add litesync-0.1.dll file to the project, but I get this error:
[image]

So I tried compile the LiteSync library from source code as explained in this [link](https://litesync.io/en/compiling.html), but I get many errors, here is one of them:
[image]

Comment: https://litesync.io/en/install-dotnet.html

Comment: @Jason please read the update.

Comment: Please don't post errors as images.  Generally speaking, sync is a hard problem and there is no great general purpose solution for all use cases.  `LiteSync` looks interest, and claims to [support Xamarin](https://litesync.io/en/mobile-database-replication-xamarin.html) but if you have issues using it you might be better off asking on their forums